# ¿Como cambiar la dirección IP de un dispositivo Android si estoy usando ethernet?

Tags: android, linux

En este caso tengo yo estoy tratando de asignarle una dirección IP a un dispositivo Android, el cual tengo conectado vía Ethernet, por medio de un adaptador. Todo bien hasta ahí, el dispositivo funciona correctamente, pero tengo la intención de cambiarle la IP por ciertos motivos, el caso es que solo encuentro tutoriales o guías en las cuales únicamente me indican como cambiar la IP, pero estando en wifi.
He intentado usar el comando: 
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.60
Pero me da que tengo denegada dicha acción. Esto lo hice cuando probé una aplicación de CLI emulation. 
Otra opción seria, usar alguna aplicación que me permita cambiar la dirección ip, pero no se cual podría usar. Me gustaría mucho que me ayudasen, porque sigo teniendo este conflicto. 
Todo esto es para una tablet Android, con la versión 7.0.

Comment: Aclara en tu pregunta que dispositivo es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes asignarle la IP desde el dispositivo que te está proporcionando la red, llamese switch, módem o router. Para ello entrarás al panel de administración del dispositivo que te está proporcionando la red y en preferencias, red o algo similar buscarás asignación de IP. La asignación de IP la haces usando la dirección MAC del dispositivo, eso lo puedes buscar fácilmente en el dispositivo Android que usas.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado compañero, ¿ud. esta usando el comando "ifconfig" en modo administrador?, aunque parezca infantil mi respuesta, dicha orden debe ir precedida del comando "sudo", esto es:

sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.60

una vez ingresada la instrucción le pedirá su contraseña de administrador, la cual deberá ingresarla de manera correcta.

Esto va solo a titulo de aclaración, nada mas, pues a veces, ingresamos comandos que necesitan dicho modo para trabajar de manera efectiva.

No obstante aqui le dejo un enlace donde encontrara el detalle de como cambiar la direccion de su dispositivo android.

https://www.adslzone.net/moviles/android/como-cambiar-la-direccion-ip-de-un-dispositivo-android/

Comment: No ese no es mi problema, conozco el comando sudo, sin embargo obviamente en un dispositivo android no conozco dicha contraseña para que dichas acciones se ejecuten. Tambien el problema repercute en que estoy buscando cambiar la direccion IP, pero cuando estoy conectando mi dispositivo por el puerto ethernet. En el modo wifi si se como se cambia la direccion ip, sin embargo en ethernet no veo que exista algun metodo.